# Why is my Django App failing on Azure with UUID invalid syntax

Tags: django, azure, uuid

My Django App runs fine locally on macOS Catalina with Python 3.8.2 and Django 3.0.5. I am deploying it to Azure as WebApp from Github selecting Python 3.8.
I have provisioned the Postgres DB, the Storage Account and the WebApp. The build process is successful.
The WebApp fails at startup with:

```
File "/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
     import uuid
File "/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uuid.py", line 138
     if not 0 <= time_low < 1<<32L:
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have verified that the uuid package is not within my requirements.txt file.
DB environment variables are set up.
Collectstatic successfully replicated my static data.
The WebApp is running with Docker.

Any help on this greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Rebuilt virtual environment and regenerated requirements.txt file and redeployed. This solved the issue.

Comment: This is Python-2.x syntax.

Comment: Have you installed a `uuid` package? The built-in uuid library would usually not be in site-packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuilding virtual environment from scratch, regenerating the requirements.txt file and then redeploying resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Don't leave ***uuid == 1.30*** or any version in your requirements.txt. If you want to use uuid library, simply a ***import uuid*** is enough cuz it is built in python3 already. This solution works for me. I am using Python 3.9.7.
Here is my Azure error log with ***uuid == 1.30*** included in requirements.txt. Hope this helps.
[Azure log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMWCU.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This is [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) syntax. In [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) there were two types of integer values: `int` and `long`. `long` had an `L` suffix at the end. An `int` had a fixed range, `long` had an arbitrary range: it could represent numbers as long as there was sufficient memory.

One could specify with the `L` suffix that this was a `long`, not an `int`. For example in [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x), one can write:

```
>>> type(1)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(1L)
<type 'long'>
```

In [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), the two merged together to `int`, and an `int` can represent arbitrary large numbers, so there is no need anymore for such suffix. You are thus using a library designed for [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) with an interpreter that interprets [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x).

I would advise not to use this (version of this) library. Take a look if there is a release for [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), or try to find an alternative. [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) is no longer supported since january 1, 2020, so it is also not a good idea to keep developing on [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x). Furthermore [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) and [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) differ in quite a large number of areas. It is not just an "extended" language. The way `map` and `filter` work is for example different. Therefore you better do not try to "fix" this issue, since likely a new one will pop up, or even worse, is hidden under the radar.

Comment: Thanks, Wilem, any hints on why Azure is installing an outdated version of UUID even though it is not in my dependencies and I have selected Python 3.8?